# Invoking JCL from Java

Tags: java, jcl

I have been working in java for the past 4 years. I would like to inform that my knowledge in mainframes system is a BIG 0 and am looking for a way to invoke a JCL scrip from a java class.

Can someone please let me know a way of doing this? What are all the per-requisites to accomplish the same?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the FTP interface to JES to submit JCL jobs:

http://www.ehow.com/how_5213702_ftp-jcl-mainframe.html

Answer (score 1):

IBM should have a Java toolkit available for interfacing with the native system. On the AS/400 (aka iSeries, i5, SystemI, ...) it was called JT/400 (Java Toolkit for the 400).  I imagine they have something very similar for the zSeries (are they called SystemZ now?) machines.

Perhaps System.exec() might be implemented in the z/OS JVM to run a system job.

---

I have been googling for a while now and can't find anything for z/OS or OS/390 comparable to JT/400; it looks like you will need to dive into JNI to do what you want, if System.exec is of no use to you.  Start with [IBM's information on using JNI in OS/390](http://www.s390.ibm.com/java/os390jni.html).

Comment: zOS Java does not really need a JT/400 equivilent. Java runs inside the USS "Unix Systems Services" environment which is a 100% compliant POSIX environment so all the standard "System" functions work as advertised without any special libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Use "System.exec()" will invoke a USS (Unix System Services) shell.

You can then use one of the USS commands to start your JCL running:

```
System.exec("tso SUBMIT 'YOUR.JCL.LIB(JOBNAME)'")
```

The JCL will then be *scheduled* -- it will run as a separate process when JES sees fit to run it -- you will not get any feedback from the job itself.

If you really want to run a legacy program and get some results back you will need to run it inside the USS shell either as a USS shell script or by invoking a TSO script from USS.